# I'm new, and I cannot for the life of me find this syntax error

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why there is a syntax error in line 12, but there seems to be one.

```
g = 0
y = 0
c = 0
while(true) {
computer = random(3);

you = choose("Choose!", "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors");

if (computer == 1){
  if (you == 2){
      show("You win!"); 
      g = g + 1;
      y = y + 1; 
 if (g == 3) {
     break; 
     show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y);
 }
} else if (you == 1) {
    show("Draw"); 
   g = g + 1; 
   if (g == 3) {
   break;
    show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y;)
  }
} else if (you == 3) {
  show("Computer wins."); 
  g = g + 1; 
 c = c + 1; 
    if (g == 3) {
     break;
      show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y;)
}
}
```

}

Comment: Well, if you formatted / indented your code properly, you might have more "luck" in spotting errors!

Comment: What do you mean? What's wrong?

Comment: One statement per line. I can spot lines with 6 separate statements. How can you develop the code if you can't even read it

Comment: "What's wrong" is that your code looks like a dogs breakfast!  It is unreadable.

Comment: Okay but I don't know what you mean specifically because I don't know what in particular it's supposed to look like

Comment: Yes to what @StephenC says, and declare your variables!  `var g = 0;` rather than `g = 0`

Comment: @HarrisonFeldman - Please [format your code properly](http://jsbeautifier.org/). You will immediately see where the problem is at.

Comment: Which line is line 12 and i believe there is some extra closing braces

Comment: Harrison - Google for "javascript style guide" and start reading.  For example: http://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml

Comment: What the others in the comments should be saying (if they weren't such jerks and had an ounce of empathy) is that you'll spend most of your time **reading** code rather than writing it. So you should take the time to learn how to write clean code because it will help you avoid wasting time trying to track down bugs (like this post). Start by reading Uncle Bob: https://books.google.ca/books/about/Clean_Code.html?id=hjEFCAAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover&hl=en and you can also check out this Javascript Style Guide: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: Yea .... but not very obvious to the OP.  Clearly.  And since the REAL problem here is that the OP's bad style habit is causing him problems, in the long term we have a win by pointing it out to him ... even if it takes him time to digest it.

Answer (score 6):

`y;)}` should be `y);}` in two places

another issue though, you have `break; show(...` in three places, the `show` I don't think will run after `break`

```
var g = 0,
    y = 0,
    c = 0;

while (true) {
    computer = random(3);

    you = choose("Choose!", "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors");

    if (computer == 1) {
        if (you == 2) {
            show("You win!");
            g = g + 1;
            y = y + 1;
            if (g == 3) {
                break; // <=== break here?
                show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y);
            }
        } else if (you == 1) {
            show("Draw");
            g = g + 1;
            if (g == 3) {
                break; // <=== break here?
                show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y;) // <=== don't wink here ;)
            }
        } else if (you == 3) {
            show("Computer wins.");
            g = g + 1;
            c = c + 1;
            if (g == 3) {
                break; // <==== break here?
                show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y;) // <=== don't wink here ;)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to beautify my code before posting

Comment: @HarrisonFeldman Generally, you should accept answers as an indication that it worked, as opposed to commenting :)

Comment: Might as well declare **all** the variables (including *computer* and *you*). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to see if you actually clean up the code.

```
g = 0
y = 0
c = 0
while (true) {
    computer = random(3);

    you = choose("Choose!", "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors");

    if (computer == 1) {
        if (you == 2) {
            show("You win!");
            g = g + 1;
            y = y + 1;
            if (g == 3) {
                break;
                show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y);
            }
        } else if (you == 1) {
            show("Draw");
            g = g + 1;
            if (g == 3) {
                break;
                show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y;)
            }
        } else if (you == 3) {
            show("Computer wins.");
            g = g + 1;
            c = c + 1;
            if (g == 3) {
                break;
                show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y;)
            }
        }
    }
```

You have several problems

1. `show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y;)` should be `show("Computer: " + c + "You: " + y);`
2. Unclosed `while` loop.
3. Undefined functions such as `random`, `choose` and `show`.
4. `break`ing before actually running code. (Although won't cause any errors, it is most likely not intended)

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing '}' at the end. Try [beautify js](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to indent your code and use jsHint to spot the error.

Answer (score -2):

Probably because you still have statements after "break;" which is unreachable.

Comment: That's bad code, but it won't cause syntax errors. jslint will probably complain about it, but not the browser.

Comment: Unlike Java, it is legal to have unreachable code in Javascript.  (Legal, but probably wrong ....)